# Adobe Illustrator: How can I align an object which is at an angle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

In Adobe Illustrator, how can I get the side of the red object to align with the side of the green object?

[image]

Comment: Just that left side of the red object? Or the entire red object unaltered, but aligned (rotated to align)?

Comment: Hi. Looks like you need to rotate it, not merely align it. Is that what you want to do? Have you tried using the Rotate tool?

Comment: The bottom anchor point is already snapped to the line, however, now I want to rotate the top portion of the red "L" shape so the complete side of the "L" shape is snapped to the line that is vertically straight, and there is no distortion to the shape.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the red elemement to highlight it, and grab the rotation tool
2. With the rotation tool, click the bottom most border that is aligned properly to set the rotation point.
   [image]
3. Grab the top of the red element, and rotate it until it is aligned properly.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. The key is to make sure Snap to Point (View menu) is enabled.
2. Using the Select tool `V`, select the L-shaped object.
3. Using the Rotation tool `R`, click the anchor point at bottom left of L-shaped object
4. Click the top left anchor point of the L-shaped object and drag over the top anchor point of the object to which to align. Release the drag when the cursor changes colour.